# Past Simple/Continuous with specific time

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

I missed my literature class today and I am calling my friend to find out what they were discussing (or discussed?) in class. My goal (as a speaker) is **to find out what was in class today**, so I can catch up

Which tense should I use:

> 1. What did Mr.Smith **speak** about in class today?
> 2. What was Mr. Smith **speaking** about in class today?

1. Are both idiomatic in this context?
2. Don't you think that "complete action" from number 1 sounds a bit odd? (because in my native language it does)

P.S. Mr. Smith is our supposed teacher

P.P.S. I am asking this because in my first language when we use the perfective aspect (basically, a verb form that conveys a completed action with the emphasis on completion, kinda similar to past simple) many verbs don't sound right, like "speak" in this context. They sound too "short" or "quick" as if the teacher's act of speaking happened in a few seconds. I wonder if it sounds ok in English?

Comment: The first is more natural than the second, but the second is also fine. Better than both would be *What did Mr. Smith **talk** about in class today?* The use of the verb *speak* here is less common.

Comment: Thanks. And a follow-up question: 
Is it true that in this context "was speaking" conveys the idea that "speaking" started at the start of the lesson and lasted until the end of the lesson? 
While if we use "speak/talk" it means it just occurred somewhere (at some point) during the class?

Comment: No, *speaking* doesn't not necessitate an unbroken series of speech from the start of the lesson to the end. That would be highly unusual. Nor does *speak* necessitate that didn't happen. Neither word means that the speech lasted longer or more continuously than the other.

Comment: I am sorry, I should've made myself clear. What I wanted to ask was: doesn't continuous aspect imply that "speaking" had repetitive nature and lasted (although with some interruptions and stops) more or less the whole class? While the simple aspect suggests that the action happened within the time period of the lesson, but didn' take the whole time.  What are your thoughts on this?  (I am sorry if I am asking the same question again, don't want to be annoying, just want to be sure I get it right)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Which is what I said in my last comment. (1) *I was **speaking** to the class about evolution this morning[, but I stopped after 5 minutes because nobody was interested].* (2) *I **spoke** to the class about evolution this morning [for the entire hour].*

Comment: See [this discussion](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/what-did-you-do-vs-what-were-you-doing.3567726/#post-18143040). To the extent that there ***is*** a difference between *What **did you do** yesterday?* and *What **were you doing** yesterday?*, it's that the ***continuous*** version emphasizes the TIME-PERIOD, rather than the ACTION. So maybe you'd be more likely to say *What did you do to get that bruise?* and *What were you doing to get so tired?* rather than the other way around.

Comment: thank you so much for the link! I'll start reading immediately