# Past Continuous with yesterday

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to use past continuous without specific time or interruption while talking about yesterday.

Here's the situation: I want to tell my friend how I spent my day yesterday. I do NOT intend to talk about any specific moment of yesterday (like "6:35" or "when you called") and neither do I want to tell a story (like "*I was playing tennis when I heard a loud bang and I ran back home and something happened etc...*") and neither do I want to add any duration (like "for 2 hours")

I have 2 options:

> a. I was playing tennis yesterday
>
> b. I played tennis yesterday

My intention is to follow up my sentence with other activities I took part in yesterday like cleaning the room and helping my father with his car. I want to describe my day yesterday.

1. which tense would be most idiomatic in this context with my intention?
2. Am I right in understanding that "a" will ALWAYS sound like a "background" for a story or a beginning of a story in this context and native speakers would always expect me to say what happened next?
3. my fellow student told me that "a" should be used in British English over "b" in this context. I find it hard to believe, is it true?

Thank you!

Comment: I answered this question here, though it was not chosen. Too bad, it's good. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222508/what-is-the-difference-between-he-was-saying-he-says-and-he-said/222512#222512

Answer (score 3):

From a previous answer by me, which you can go and look up. I have basically answered this question three times.

The past continuous:

The past continuous (also called past progressive) is a verb tense which is used to show that an ongoing past action was happening at a specific moment of interruption, or that two ongoing actions were happening at the same time. Read on for detailed descriptions, examples, and past continuous exercises.

Statement: You were studying when she called. Question: Were you studying when she called? Negative: You were not studying when she called.

***The Trick with the Past Continuous***
**The trick is this: Even if there is not actual "when" or "while" or "as" in the sentence, these are always implied.**

**There is always the idea of something that defines the moment in time when the was/verbING is being used.**

So, "He was saying that he is going to leave soon." would imply either:

as he was getting ready to leave. OR
when we arrived at the house.
**Those are examples of implied time limiters.**

The he said/he says examples are obvious. One is present; one is past.

The present continuous can be used with a simple past tense.

He said we have a good chance of winning the game.
He said it in the past, but the game has not yet been played. If the game had been played, he would have said:

He said we had a good chance of winning the game. [the game has been played]
English page [past continuous](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html)**

**Conclusion**: If someone asks you:
A person: What were you doing yesterday?
You may answer:
B Person: I was playing tennis.
A Person: Ah, that's why you didn't answer your phone.

[Implication: You didn't answer your phone because you were playing tennis when I called.]

QUESTION: Can you see that the person asking the question had something in mind by using the past continuous? And that it becomes clear at the end of the exchange?

***As for what your friend said, there is absolutely no difference here in terms of British or American English. Nothing at all.*** When telling someone about your day, there would be no reason to use the past continuous unless it is time limited by implication in the wider conversation. Otherwise, the simple past is best. Sometimes, the wider context of a conversation can color all the tenses used:

**CONTRASTING CONVERSATIONAL SCENARIOS**

1. John wants to tell his friend what **he was so busy doing laundry yesterday** that he **didn't answer** any of his phone calls.
   VERSUS
2. John wants to tell his friend **what he did yesterday** so his friend can understand how busy he really was.

Comment: I read your old post some time ago and want to thank you for changing it to answer my specific question. Although I fully understand the concept of "implied moment in time" There's still one thing that remains unclear to me. Does the concept of "moment in time" include the time periods that are just slightly longer than a moment, like "a class" or "during a telephone call' or "my trip to work". (like 60-120 min periods) For example:

**- "Didn't you get bored on your way to work?"**

**- "Of course not, I was playing/played (??) my GameBoy"**

Comment: Dmitriy Please read the conversational scenarios. But you have answered your own question: Didn't you get bored [simple past] on your way to work? Answer: Of course not, I was playing Gameboy. Implication: I didn't get bored because I was playing x. See? The conversational scenario involves two people and so does the actual moment in time. It is not just the single person. The moment in time is the moment that is OVER (get bored) versus the other won that lasts OVER some period of time (playing Gameboy).

Comment: Can this logic be different in interrogative sentences?
Because I was told in some other thread here ( https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252341/past-simple-continuous-with-specific-time)  that when asking about the class that I missed,  I should say
"what did the teacher talk about?" instead of "what was he talking about"? (the latter being less idiomatic). Is it because the speakers haven't yet introduced any "implied moment" at the time of speaking? (as opposed to "I didn't get bored") Or is it because "a class" doesn't count as a moment?

Comment: The class is over and you want to know what you **missed**. So, What **did I miss**? would be the most usual. versus: Since you yourself said you missed it, the logical tense is simple past here. There is no reason to use the PC.

Comment: @Lambie I think it's worth putting the question this way. If there **isn't** any important point in the past of which we're talking about, but there are still two simultaneous actions that went on over a certain period of past time, which of these two works better the past simple or the past continuous in both clauses? 1) *"I read a book **while** she cooked dinner"* or 2) *"I was reading a book **while** she was cooking dinner".*

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov That is not about grammar. It's about what **you want to say**: Do you want to emphasize the ongoing action in the past or just tell us what you did while she cooked dinner?

Comment: @Lambie, my teacher used to say that with two simultaneous actions, we have to use the continuous aspect in both clauses, so I thought using the past simple might sound off. Are you sure *"I read a book **while** she cooked dinner"* is fine even if the idea is that two actions **went on** over a certain period of past time?

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov If actions are simultaneous, sure: I was reading while she cooked dinner. But you can also do: I was reading while she was cooking dinner. AGAIN: It depends on what **you want to say** and not the grammar per se. Do you want to emphasize both ongoing actions or not?

Comment: I'm not sure if the goal is to emphasize both ongoing actions. It's just something that happened yesterday. @Lambie, do I understand you correctly? If I want to emphasize both ongoing actions, I should use the past continuous in both clauses, *"I was reading a book while she was cooking dinner",* but if I do **not** have any particular reason to emphasize both ongoing actions, it should be *"I read a book while she cooked dinner"*?

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov Yes and no. The choices are two past continuous verbs, two simple past verbs or either one in either clause. Like this: I was reading a book while she cooked dinner. OR I read a book while she was cooking dinner. These last two examples were not in your last comment.

Comment: @Lambie English Grammar in Use, by Raymond Murphy, Cambridge University Press has these two sentences: *"I **read** a book while she **watched** TV"* and *"Violet **got** ready while I **cooked** the dinner".* The description to the second example says: [two long actions]. To be honest, these two sentences struck me as rather odd, what about you? Do you think these two sentences would sound better if one of (or both) the clauses in each sentence was in the past continuous?

Comment: @IlyaTretyakov No, those sentences are fine but can also follow the tenses I have in my previous comment. It all depends on what **you want to say**.

Comment: @Lambie OK, thanks. *"It all depends on what **you want to say"***, but what is it? You said that all combinations are fine but what should make me choose one over the other? Let's say there's no specific point in the past, I'm not emphasizing the ongoing nature of the actions, I'm just stating a fact of what (among other things) happened yesterday, but those are two simultaneous actions that went on/lasted over the same period of past time. So, which would you choose? 1) *"I **read** a book while she **cooked** dinner"* or 2) *"I **was reading** a book while she **was cooking** dinner".*

Answer (score 0):

### Past Continuous may be used in such a case

The past continuous (or past progressive) construction is normally used to describe a past event that is still ongoing, or one that was interuppted by a subsequent event, or a series of past events (which seems to be what the OP mans by "a story". It is formed with the past tense of "*to be*" ("was" or "were") plus the present participle of ther main verb ("-ing" form).

Some possible examples:

> - I was playing tennis when two cars crashed in the street. [Interruption]
> - I was playing tennis. Then I went home and had lunch. [Sequence]
> - I was playing tennis for the last 30 hours withotu a break. [Ongoing]

Now let us consider some possible conversational exchanges.

> Alice: What did you do yesterday?
> Bob: I played tennis.

> Carol : What did you do yesterday?
> Dave: I was playing tennis.

A fluent speaker might make either Bob's response or Dave's. I think strictly speaking Bob's response using the past simple is more 'correct". But many speakers would make Dave's response with the past continuous,  and so it cannot be considered "wrong". Furthermore consider a sinmialr but longer exchange:

> Ellen: What did you do yesterday?
> Fred: I was playing tennis. Then I cleaned my room. And then i helped my father with the yard work. And then we had dinner.

Fred's response involves a sequence of events, which makes it clearly appropriate to use the past continuous construction, although the simple past could also be used, and the meaning would be much the same.

#### Sources

*English Club*'s [page on "Past Continious"](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_past-continuous.htm) reads:

> The Past Continuous tense is an important tense in English. We use it to say what we were in the middle of doing at a particular moment in the past.
>
> ...
>
> The Past Continuous tense expresses action at a particular moment in the past. The action started before that moment but has not finished at that moment. For example, yesterday I watched a film on TV. The film started at 7pm and finished at 9pm.

The *EF* [page on "Past continuous tense"](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/past-continuous-tense/) reads:

> The past continuous describes actions or events in a time before now, which began in the past and were still going on when another event occurred.
>
> It is used:
>
> - Often, to describe the background in a story written in the past tense, e.g. "The sun was shining and the birds were singing as the elephant came out of the jungle. The other animals were relaxing in the shade of the trees, but the elephant moved very quickly. She was looking for her baby, and she didn't notice the hunter who was watching her through his binoculars. When the shot rang out, she was running towards the river..."
> - to describe an unfinished action that was interrupted by another event or action, e.g. "I was having a beautiful dream when the alarm clock rang."
> - to express a change of mind: e.g. "I was going to spend the day at the beach but I've decided to get my homework done instead."
> - with 'wonder', to make a very polite request: e.g. "I was wondering if you could baby-sit for me tonight."

None that neither of these sources suggest using this construction when describing a single event unrelated to any other event. However, many fluent speakers might well use the construction in that way, and such use would certainly be understood. However, in that case, the use of the simple past might be better writing.